# Is it possible to add a footnote depending on the page contents when using itext?

Tags: java, itext

I am using Itext 5.5 and right now, I have a custom implementation of `PdfPageEventHelper` that adds a footer to the page containing Page number information.

Recent changes in my application lead to the existence of necessary footnotes. The way I am creating the PDF (dynamically created from a list of Components) makes it effectively impossible to determine which page contains which items, as that is part of customizable Styling options.

However, I need to add explanations to the footnote markers.
The approach I have now is to simply notify the `PdfPageEventHelper` that, somewhere in the document, there is at least one element that needs the (currently only) footnote, and then I add the explanatory footnote to *every* Page.

This is something I want to avoid, as the future might bring more footnotes and explanations.
So the question is:

Can I parse the current page content directly and scan for the existence of marker text? Or is there another way to see if the current page needs the explanatory footnote?

My failed approaches so far (all in `onEndPage(PdfWriter, Document)`):

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(cb.toPdf(writer());
// this led to InvalidPdfException
----
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.getCompositeElements();
// returned null, I expected the current page contents
----
OutputStreamCounter oc = writer.getOs();
// did not expose any useful methods. also, cannot read from OutputStream
```

Googling the problem yielded dozens of results - how to add a page number or how to add a document-static, user-specific header. But nothing page-depending.

Oh, and this, which is not really helpful:
[Adding a pdf footer conditionally on certain pages in a multi-page pdf document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383651/adding-a-pdf-footer-conditionally-on-certain-pages-in-a-multi-page-pdf-document)

which seems basically to be the exact same problem as mine.

Comment: Essentially you'll have to do it the other way around: Simply add a *generic tag* to the chunk of a footnote marker. Then your page event listener is informed about this generic tag between the start of the page and the end of it. If you set a flag in `onGenericTag`, therefore, your `onEndPage` method merely has to check (and later reset) that flag and add the footnote accordingly. You can even use the generic tag text to differentiate between different markers and only add the matching footnotes. See [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events-itext5/page-events-chunks).

Comment: would you like to add that as an answer? because that works like a charm =) Thank you very much

Comment: Here you are! I'm happy I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you'll have to do it the other way around:

Simply add a *generic tag* to the chunk of a footnote marker. Then your page event listener is informed about this generic tag between the start of the page and the end of it. If you set a flag in `onGenericTag`, therefore, your `onEndPage` method merely has to check (and later reset) that flag and add the footnote accordingly.

You can even use the generic tag text to differentiate between different markers and only add the matching footnotes.

For an example use of generic tags, have a look at examples using the `Chunk.setGenericTag(String)` method, e.g. the sandbox example [GenericFields](https://github.com/itext/i5js-sandbox/blob/master/src/main/java/sandbox/events/GenericFields.java).

*(I originally referenced the iText site URL https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events-itext5/page-events-chunks but due to a restructuring of that site it leads nowhere specific anymore; but you can still find [a copy of the original page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170819135135/http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events-itext5/page-events-chunks) using the wayback machine.)*